# What is the difference between using native Angular CLI toolkit, LernaJS, and ng-packagr?

Tags: angular, lerna, ng-packagr

I am not new to Angular, but I am new to writing my own Angular component libraries so I have been trying to learn more about how to build your own libraries and make them accessible via `npm`. So far there have been 3 tools that I have found that appear to have a lot of community/traction around them.

1. [LernaJS](https://lernajs.io/)
2. [ng-packagr](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr)
3. [Native Angular CLI](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries)

As I understand it, LernaJS is a framework agnostic package management tool that appears to be primarily useful for managing symlinks between packages that are highly dependent on one another without having to manage the links yourself. Also comes with ability to publish all of the packages using a unified semantic versioning strategy.

Then there is ng-packagr which I see has a large community of collaborators and I have found a couple of tutorials and articles around how to use ng-packagr to build all of the different types of module bundles needed for different scenarios (ESM, FESM, AMD, UMD, etc). My first attempts at using this tool didn't go so well as I had issues with the tool copying package.json files into the `dist` folder which would alter relative paths and cause me issues. I'm sure this was an issue on my part and not one with the tool.

Lastly there is the native Angular CLI that allows you to use `ng new [workspace-name] --create-application=false` which will create a "blank" Angular workspace to begin building libraries. Inside that workspace I can then use `ng generate library [name]` to create my libraries and then finally `ng generate application [name]` to create a "sandbox" application hosted on `localhost:4200` which I can use to test out the component libraries.

In my limited experience, the 3rd option seemed to work the best for me. I ran into no issues getting the CLI to generate me the libraries and having the "sandbox" application import those modules/components and use them accordingly. It also is a native Angular tool so I know it will always follow the Angular conventions which is attractive to me.

So my question is, are there still benfits to using LernaJS and/or ng-packagr or were those just solutions to this problem before Angular built their own solution?

Comment: So something I just realized actually is that the Angular CLI is actually using `ng-packagr` itself to perform the build. Did not realize that until I ran a `npm install` and noticed that `ng-packagr` was installed. So it appears the Angular team has simply wrapped the  functionality up into their own CLI for ease of use.